# Using toPrecision with map method

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a function that returns long numbers. 23.23423423423432

I can strip the decimal places:

```
function shortNumbers(){
    var longNumber = 34.324234234234;
    var shortNumber = longNumber.toPrecision(2)
    alert("Shorter number is " + shortNumber)
  }
```

Next I want to use map to display the values in an alert:

```
function collectVideoValues(){  
    var loopsStr = loops.map(x=>x.start+"AA"+x.end).join('AA');
    alert("Video Values are " + videoId + "," +loopsStr );
  }
```

Can I insert toPrecision after loops.map ?

```
loops.map.toPrecision(2).(x=>x.start+"AA"+x.end).join('AA');
```

I'd like to solve this in 1 or 2 lines of code without making a second function.

Answer (score 0):

I placed toPrecision after x.start and x.end to strip the decimal places from the number.

```
function collectVideoValues(){  
    var loopsStr = loops.map(x=>x.start.toPrecision(2)+"i"+x.end.toPrecision(2)).join('i');
    document.getElementById("lesson-code").innerHTML= videoId + "ID"+ loopsStr;
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Explanation added!